# Add a data attribute to an a tag and retrieve it using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a bit of a problem. I have several `a` tags. I would like to assign a `data` attribute to each and reference the value of the `data` attribute using `JQuery`. I would then like to set the value of a hidden field in my form to this `data` attribute.

However, I am unsure of how to do this. Currently I have this link.

```
<a href="" class="myclass" name="hello">Say Hello</a>
```

In my `JQuery` I would like to be able to get the `name` value....

Something like this ....

```
$(".myclass").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.attr('name'));
});
```

and output the value `hello`

Comment: `e` refers to jQuery event, you want to target the clicked element. You can just use `this` or even in your case `e.target`, both needing to be wrapped in jq object to use any jq method on it, e.g: `$(this)`. FYI, `name` isn't a data attribute, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a click handler `this` is the DOM element clicked.

Use `$(this)` to convert it to a jQuery object and use the `attr` on that:

```
$(".myclass").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much that's working. Will accept this as answer when I can!